# AJAX call runs MySQL delete query fine but doesn't hide table row deleted from page

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, fadeout

I have a script which runs an AJAX call to delete a specified row from a table of data. The query runs fine and the record is deleted from the database but I can't get the row in the table the user is browsing when they click the delete button to hide. I think I remember that `jQuery` has issues with `td/tr` and this is perhaps it, but even after trying to put each table row inside its own div to make reference to I've still had no luck.

The ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //##### Send delete Ajax request to response.php #########
    //$("body").on("click", "#responds .del_button", function(e) {
        $("body").on("click", ".del_button", function(e) {
         e.returnValue = false;
         var clickedID = this.id.split('-'); //Split string (Split works as PHP explode)
         var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
         var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "ajax/education_response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //Form variables
            success:function(response){
                //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
                $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut("slow");
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
    });
    $('html, body').stop();

});
```

And the structure I am playing around with to populate the table (I know it's a mess with the `divs` for each row but as I say I'm sure I remember `jQuery` doesn't like `tr/td`. I've used this ajax call on other pages and the `fadeout()` works correctly in all other cases, so sure it must be because I'm trying to remove individual rows from the front end table.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $catid = $row['id'];
    $catsector = $row['job_sector'];
    $cattype = $row['job_type'];
    $catname = $row['job_name'];
    echo "<div id=item_".$catid.">";
    echo "<tr class=''>";
    echo "<td>$catsector</td>";
    echo "<td>$cattype</td>";
    echo "<td>$catname</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='#' class='del_button' id='del-". $catid ."'>Delete CV</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";           
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I would guess its because you have a div wrapping a `tr`... thats not valid. You should also enclose your attributes in `"` so: `echo '<div id="item_'.$catid.">';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure

        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "ajax/education_response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:myData, //Form variables
        success:function(response){
            //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
            $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut("slow");
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            //On error, we alert user
            alert(thrownError);
        }
     });
```

for

```
  var that = this;
  var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure

        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "ajax/education_response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:myData, //Form variables
        success:function(response){
            //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
                 $(that).closest('tr').fadeOut("slow"); // will works faster 
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            //On error, we alert user
            alert(thrownError);
        }
  });
```

Also is useful to make changes in markup in accord to Aguardientico's answer.

Comment: Thanks @YD1m , it was the use of closest that I had been doing wrong before I started playing around with divs inside the table. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
echo "<div id=item_".$catid.">";
```

and

```
echo "</div>";
```

and change

```
echo "<tr class=''>";
```

for

```
echo "<tr class='' id=item_".$catid.">";
```

Comment: Cheers @Aguardientico have updated the markup and changed my script per YD1m's answer below

Comment: Good to know that you fix the issue :)